# Remove a character from elements in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, gsub

I have a set of data where some elements are preceded by "<" and I need to remove "<" so that I can perform some data analysis. The data is saved in a .txt file and I'm bringing it into R using read.table. Below is an example of what the text file looks like.

```
Background: 18 <10 27 22 <3

Site: 30 44 23 <16 13
```

I used `x=read.file` to make a dataframe, then tried `gsub("<","",x)` to remove the `"<"` and the result is something completely unexpected, at least to me. This is what I get as a result.

```
[1] "1:2"       "c(18, 30)" "1:2"       "c(27, 23)" "c(2, 1)"   "1:2"
```

I have no idea what that means or why it's happening. I would greatly appreciate explanation both of what is going on here, and how I should go about accomplishing my goal.

Comment: `gsub` doesn't work on a `data.frame` directly - `x[] <- lapply(x, gsub, pattern="<", replacement="")` I'm guessing might be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "Background   Site
                 18   30
                 <10  44
                 27   23
                 22  <16
                 <3   13", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

You can use `mutate_at` and apply the `gsub` function to the variables (i.e. `Background` and `Site`) which you wish to remove the preceding `<` sign.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_at(vars(Background, Site), 
                 funs(as.numeric(gsub("^<", "", .))))
```

The output is:

```
  Background Site
1         18   30
2         10   44
3         27   23
4         22   16
5          3   13
```

Comment: Seems like the data is more like `x <- read.table(text = "18 <10 27 22 <3\n30 44 23 <16 13")`, just judging from the output of their attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Read the file with `readLines`, perform the `gsub` and then re-read it with `read.table`.  No packages are used:

```
read.table(text = gsub("<", "", readLines("myfile")), as.is = TRUE)
```

If the data does not come from a file but is already in a data frame `DF` then define a `clean` function which cleans a column of `DF` and apply it to each numeric column:

```
clean <- function(x) as.numeric(gsub(">", "", x))
DF[-1] <- lapply(DF[-1], clean)
```